# Firebase Android, checking if an object (with multiple children) exists

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using a Firebase Database to store user’s reports. Each user is allowed to submit only 10 different reports.

In the example below we have a user named “Jasna Kuljancic” who has submitted 3 reports.

[image]

My question is how can you check if a user has submitted a particular report already?

I would have to check the values of "location", "mode", "spinnerOne" and compare them to what the user just entered and if it’s already there then don't add to the database and if it is, then add it. Here is my attempt:

```
public void checkifentryExistofNot() {
                uniqueID = mDatabaseReference.push().getKey();
                fullname = “Jasna Kuljancic”;
                CATEGORY = “Clinical First”); 

                final Report subreport = new Report(SELECTED_LOCATION,
                        locationEditText.getText().toString(),
                        modeEditText.getText().toString(),
                        Integer.parseInt(dateEditText.getText().toString()));

                mDatabaseReference.child("Students Reports").child(fullname).child(CATAGORY).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                int numberofCount = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                if (numberofCount == 0) {

                    mDatabaseReference.child("Students Reports").child(fullname).child(CATAGORY).child(uniqueID).setValue(subreport);

                }

                if (numberofCount != 0) {

                    for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Report datareports = child.getValue(Report.class);
                        thelocation = datareports.getLocation();
                        themode = datareports.getMode();

                        if (thelocation.equals(locationEditText.getText().toString()) && themode.equals(modeEditText.getText().toString())) {
                            break;
                        } else {
                            mDatabaseReference.child("Students Reports").child(fullname).child(CATAGORY).child(uniqueID).setValue(subreport);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
```

The issue with my solution is that the for loop will check over each report and in each case it will either add a new report or not but this will happen over the number of reports that exist and it should only do it once.

In other words, if we have 3 entries and each time it does not exist, it will submit the report 3 times (which is not really bad). But if it checks the first report and it does exist the loop will exit since I have a “break” in there (this is good) but let’s say the second report is the one that is going to be a duplicate, it would have already added it to the database because the first entry was not a duplicate.

I feel like I am over doing this and there should be a much quicker way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase queries can only order/filter by a single property. So there is no `WHERE` clause within Firebase. What should you do instead, is to couple a compound value named `location_mode_spinnerOne`. Your database structure should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   -- Students Reports
         |
         -- Jasna Kuljancic
               |
               -- Clinical First
                     |
                     -- -KuVRQ4OjdfKXCNdLWzb
                            |
                            --- data: 3939393
                            |
                            --- location: "fifififi"
                            |
                            --- mode: "ododododo"
                            |
                            --- spinnerOne: "Asylum Hill Family Clinic"
                            |
                            --- location_mode_spinnerOne: "fifififi_ododododo_Asylum Hill Family Clinic"
```

As you probably see, i have added the new compound value `location_mode_spinnerOne` for each particular category. This means that you can query your Firebase database according to this new `location_mode_spinnerOne` field. Assuming that the above database structure is correct, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference categoryRef = rootRef.child("Students Reports").child(fullname).child(CATAGORY);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String searchedText = "fifififi";

        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String location_mode_spinnerOne = ds.child("location_mode_spinnerOne").getValue(String.class);
            if(!location_mode_spinnerOne.contains(searchedText)) {
                categoryRef.child(uniqueID).setValue(subreport);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
categoryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

I gave you an example for searching `fifififi` keyword. The `searchedText` text would be the exact searched text typed by the user.

To better understanding, i suggest you see this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKFLI5FOOHs&index=4&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s&t=544s).

Comment: for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            String location_mode_spinnerOne = ds.child("alltogether").getValue(String.class);
                            if(!location_mode_spinnerOne.equals(datacombined)) {
                                categoryref.child(uniqueID).setValue(subreport);
                                Log.d("awesome", "submitted");
                            } else {  Log.d("awesome", "not submitted");  }   }   
This works except it adds data to firebase even though it goes to the “not submitted” condition. Why is that?

Comment: Thanks a lot Atif AbbAsi, mark42inbound, Alex!! Your answers are very helpful!

Comment: Even without the else loop it does that, that's y I ended up trying the else condition.

Comment: But it does not print anything. Thanks Mido! Cheers!

Comment: unfortunately it does, which is odd to me. The code makes sense and the android monitor but it keeps adding data whether its new or a duplicate still.

Comment: its the same issue I had with the for loop before. If it checks on the first item and its different from what the user input, it will add that report even though it can exist on the 3rd for loop (3rd entry in the database).

Comment: In this new node, there is exactly on field `location_mode_spinnerOne`. Cannot add tree times. Try to add the values to an ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() it will show you total number of children's.!
All you have to do is make a Model class save your value in objects and while editing check if object has same data then don't update data and if its different then update data.!

Answer (score 1):

There're two approaches to this problem. I think for the first approach you've quite figured it how to do so. Only missing thing is to separate the sequential actions of [a] validating the uniqueness of the report and [b] adding the object to the database. There might be a button press for adding the report. I suggest, on the button press get the data snapshot of the required table. As the uniqueness of the report is restricted a single user, fetch all the reports for a single user. Then simply compare the target report with the fetched reports and proceed accordingly. If unique then add or report a duplicate otherwise. The difference (w.r.t your code) is no event listener would be attached. And I think your code processing inline with Firebase data. Here you'll get the data dump, compare it and then update it.

Another approach is to leverage the rules provided by Firebase. Basically, it's same as the first approach, but all work is done by firebase. Here's the code for inserting only unique usernames to Firebase:

```
 "usernames": {
  "$usernameid": {
  ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null  && (!data.exists() || !newData.exists())"
  }
 }
```

In the context of your question, you check the uniqueness of the report based on three values. Add the rules for all three values. This would allow inserting the unique reports for each user. But be sure to add the rules correctly as for the scope of the rule must be for a single user, not for all the reports in the database.